# Why the blue dots (indicating that the code was compiled) do not appear?

Tags: delphi

I put several 3rd party controls in a DPK file in order to install them all with a single click when I (re)install Delphi.
One of the controls in this DPK is Melander's GIFImage.pas. The thing is that the blue dots do not appear in this file when I compile the package. Why?

The file IS compiled. I have deleted the DCU and I put some garbage text that cannot be compiled and the compiler indeed stopped at that line and complained that it cannot compile the file. No DCU was generated and the compilation and the entire DPK failed. Then I deleted the garbage text and recompiled. It worked and the DCU was generated. So the file was compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silly me. Some time ago I put the ($D-} directive in that file.
The file is full with other directives so it was difficult to find/observe that little D- thing.

Hm... My memory starts to fail me....